# docker build uses wrong Dockerfile content (bug?)

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I have been using docker for years and now I have found a very strange behavior: the `docker build` command uses a Dockerfile which is not the one I have.

See next log:

```
PS D:\reposNovabase\charmander\charmanderWarehouse> type Dockerfile  
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.11_9_openj9-0.26.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY build/libs/charmanderWarehouse-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
EXPOSE 8083
CMD ["java", "-Xmx70m", "-jar", "charmanderWarehouse-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
PS D:\reposNovabase\charmander\charmanderWarehouse> docker build -f Dockerfile -t javiersedano/charmander-warehouse:test1 .
[+] Building 0.2s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.11_9_openj9-0.26.0-alpine                                                           0.0s 
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.11_9_openj9-0.26.0-alpine                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 57B                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => ERROR [3/3] COPY build/libs/charmanderPurchases-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app                                                                                           0.0s 
------
 > [3/3] COPY build/libs/charmanderPurchases-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/build/libs/charmanderPurchases-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" not found: not found
PS D:\reposNovabase\charmander\charmanderWarehouse>
```

See how the Dockerfile uses

```
COPY build/libs/charmanderWarehouse-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
```

but the `docker build` fails with

```
ERROR [3/3] COPY build/libs/charmanderPurchases-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
```

Why is it trying to copy charmanderPurchases?!!

More hints: the file is failing (charmanderPurchases) is used in a previous Dockerfile in a brother project which is built a second before (all of this is part of a pseudo-CI .cmd process that builds a few images).

More hints: I have a workaround. If I use

```
type Dockerfile | build -f - -t javiersedano/charmander-warehouse:test1 .
```

then it works as expected; furthermore, after this workaround, the first command also works as expected... but then, the build that fails is the build of the brother project, because charmanderPurchases tries to COPY charmanderWarehouse... WTF?!

Looks like the Dockerfile content itself is being cached or something, and it is reusing a previous Dockerfile.

Environment: Docker Desktop for Windows 3.6.0 on Windows 10 using the WSL2 backend.

Edit1: tested with 4.0.1 and still fails.

Any hint? Any idea?

Comment: Is the tag you're giving to this project and the brother project the same? Or do that reside in the same directory? I think you're right about caching, not so much for the reason why...

Comment: They are not the same tag (each tag is built and pushed to docker hub). They neither reside in the same directory (the .cmd does essentially `cd dir1; docker build -t dir1:latest; cd ..; cd dir2; docker build -t dir2:latest; cd ..;`)

Comment: I see, thanks for the response, can you try to maybe restart the docker service? maybe it stuck in some obscure state

Comment: Does not help. Actually, I have upgraded to the latest versions n (so restarting in the process).

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**(See edit2 below for the final solution)**

Regarding your error, it could be coming from a `.dockerignore` file
excluding `charmanderWarehouse-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` or one of its parent (maybe `build`)

If it is not coming from .dockerignore, you could try option `--no-cache=true` to build your image without cache reusing.

`docker build --no-cache=true -f Dockerfile -t javiersedano/charmander-warehouse:test1 .`

More information here :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options

**EDIT:**

Dockerfile content not being updated seems to be due to the context not being updated by the builder for files with same size/timestamp :
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1368

Here is a possible workaround :
`docker builder prune` between each build.

**EDIT 2, by Javier Sedano:**

After reading the github thread, looks like the problem is the following: Docker caches the Dockerfile and uses the timestamp and filesize as key for the chache. In my case, the Dockerfiles only differ on purchases/warehouse... which are both 9 characters-long... so the Dockerfiles have the same size. The timestamp are the same because they were downloaded as .zip files from GitLab.

Workarounds (I have tested them and all of them worked for me, so the choice depends on the rest of constraints):

A.-Use `cat Dockerfile | docker build -f - -t xxxx:tttt`

B.-Modify the files not to have the same size (I do not like this solution because it may conflict again in the future).

C.-Use `docker builder prune -f` before building.

Comment: There is no .dockerignore . Also, notice that the root problem is not that it is not finding the file. The root problem is that it is using a Dockerfile content which is not the Dockerfile that I am declaring in the cli... so such wrong Dockerfile refers to another file and then it is not found. But the root problem is why is it using a Dockerfile which is not what I told it?

Comment: Tried --no-cache and --no-cache=true, without success.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it seems related to the `build context` which is defined when invoking `docker build` and maybe a known bug.

Comment: I do not think it is the context, because the file is searched (and not found) in the right folder. So looks like it is setting the right context. Only the Dockerfile content is wrong.

Comment: Still have not tested the workarounds given in the thread, but I will, and report back in a few hours.

Comment: It works. I am editing your answer to summarize the result and accept your answer to give you credit.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. What I don't understand is why is docker caching Dockerfile. It doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I seem to get bitten by this bug for a file other than the Dockerfile. It too "randomly" gets the value from a "brother file", with the same name,size and modification date, but different contents, in a different but similarly structured docker directory tree that has previously been built. Presumably workaround (A) above would not help, but I tried (C), docker builder prune -f and that helped (I only tried once).